I recently upgraded dell latitude to Ubuntu 24.04. Wifi is connecting but I need to run dhcpcd on restart and after some time
Following is the output for sudo dhcpcd which I need to run every time on startup and after some time.

dhcpcd-10.0.6 starting 
dev: loaded udev 
DUID 00:01:00:01:2e:66:05:b4:a0:80:69:82:e0:ba 
Dropped protocol specifier '.link' from 'enp44s0.link'. Using 'enp44s0' (ifindex=2). 
wlp0s20f3: connected to Access Point: Cobra_5GHz 
enp44s0: waiting for carrier 
wlp0s20f3: IAID 69:82:e0:ba 
wlp0s20f3: rebinding lease of 192.168.1.49 
wlp0s20f3: probing address 192.168.1.49/24 
wlp0s20f3: soliciting an IPv6 router 
wlp0s20f3: leased 192.168.1.49 for 86400 seconds 
wlp0s20f3: adding route to 192.168.1.0/24 
wlp0s20f3: adding default route via 192.168.1.1 
Dropped protocol specifier '.dhcp' from 'wlp0s20f3.dhcp'. Using 'wlp0s20f3' (ifindex=3). 

Thanks.

Answer To This Link Worked
"activation of network connection failed" error for the all my wifi connections

